# How to convert a list of String lists to a list of objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, collections

I'm reading a .csv file that returns a list of String lists, **recipiesList**, in the following format:

*List(List(Portuguese Green Soup, Portugal), List(Grilled Sardines, Portugal), List(Salted Cod with Cream, Portugal))*

I have a class Recipe, which has been defined in the following manner:

```
case class Recipe(name: String, country: String)
```

Is there any immediate way that I can transform recipiesList into a list of type List[Recipe]? Such as with map or some sort of extractor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transform elements of a `List` using the `map` method:

```
val input = List(List("Portuguese Green Soup", "Portugal"),
    List("Grilled Sardines", "Portugal"),
    List("Salted Cod with Cream", "Portugal"))

val output = input map { case List(name, country) => Recipe(name, country) }
```

Comment: It's safer to use `collect` instead of `map` when the given function is partial. That way, if your data is corrupt (say some element in `input` as three elements for some reason), it will simply be ignored, rather than throwing a `MatchError`.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet, if my team start writing code that silently ignores errors in the input, I'll be having words! Better to use a `case _` and do something with the errors

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, I'd rather silently ignore them than let them break my production app. My main point was that `map` with a partial function is not pure, it introduces (probably) unexpected errors, and should be avoided, when possible.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet " I'd rather silently ignore them than let them break my production app" False dichotomy. You don't have to ignore them to avoid breaking the app

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I completely agree with you. But using `map` with only the expected case will break the app on unexpected cases. I like your idea with `case _` which makes the function total, I just try to alert on the fact that you should not use a partial function where a total one is expected. In fact, if it where a sealed trait instead of `List[String]` as input type, the scala compiler itself would issue a warning.

Answer (score 3):

The quick way would be:

```
recipiesList.map(s => Recipe(s(0), s(1))
```